# Java thread affinity

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling, setthreadaffinitymask

Does anybody know of a way to lock down individual threads within a Java process to specific CPU cores (on Linux)? I've done this in C, but can't find how to do this in Java. My instincts are that this will require a JNI call, but I was hoping someone here might have some insight or might have done it before.

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below to Hassan's comment. Some threads are very I/O intensive, others are CPU intensive. If I'm shielding I/O interrupts to a particular core, I'd like the I/O intensive threads to be on cores on the same socket, and I'd like to shield the CPU-intensive threads from the I/O.

Comment: @gimpf: as always with this type of "question questionning": SO is not about the "why", it's about the "how".  CPU affinity exists for a reason, there's a reason there are utilities under both Linux and Windows to set a process's CPU affinity.  The OP's question is a perfectly valid question that wants no "why" but a "how".

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: I doubt that the "why" is forbidden on SO, and as Java is usually not the first programming language for concurrency-related performance tweaks, I think a sanity check is valid.

Comment: Right now I need the answer to this question in order to implement NUMA optimisations.

Comment: I love these "Why you want to do this questions?" If a serious engineer ask something please think about it might be serious answer required.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't do this in pure java. But if you really need it -- you can use JNI to call native code which do the job. This is the place to start with:

http://ovatman.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-java-jni-to-set-thread-affinity.html

http://blog.toadhead.net/index.php/2011/01/22/cputhread-affinity-in-java/

**UPD:** After some thinking, I've decided to create my own class for this: [ThreadAffinity.java](http://tools.assembla.com/Behemoth/browser/Tests/JAVA/test/src/main/java/test/threads/ThreadAffinity.java) It's JNA-based, and very simple -- so, if you want to use it in production, may be you should spent some time making it more stable, but for benchmarking and testing it works well as is.

**UPD 2:** There is another [library](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity) for working with thread affinity in java. It uses same method as previously noted, but has another interface

Comment: +1 Works!  Awesome!  Note the comment I left in the first blog - you need `#define _GNU_SOURCE` above all the includes.

Comment: +1: I have turned this functionality into a library which uses JNI or JNA depending on what is available.  It also has a low latency timer and support busy waiting with the PAUSE asm instruction. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's great, thanks! (assuming it works which I have yet to verify). There are some issues with your library (mostly documentation and a bug), though; how can I contact you about that?

Comment: Best to log bugs this way https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity/issues so they don't get forgotten

Comment: This is really the best way to do it, although my way below works too.

Comment: Both links are not working. This question is still relevant. Can you please updated the links?

Comment: Don't know how to bring the blogs back :) But the idea is pretty simple, you just do appropriate syscalls via JNA/JNI. Details may be found in 3 or 4 links

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I found this ... Thanks again on the other thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866123/java-relationship-between-threads-and-cpus/13866186?noredirect=1#comment53518747_13866186

Answer (score 9):

I know it's been a while, but if anyone comes across this thread, here's how I solved this problem. I wrote a script that would do the following:

1. "jstack -l "
2. Take the results, find the "nid"'s of the threads I want to manually lock down to cores.
3. Taskset those threads.

Comment: Out of interest, I thought taskset only worked on processes not individual threads. What is the syntax for doing it to a thread?

Comment: Java code isn't machine code being executed by a processor, it is data being scanned and interpreted by another program (the JVM).  The JVM may implement threads in a completely arbitrary manner.  Even if the JVM spawns additional processes to execute threads there is no guarantee that when a thread gets dropped it will get picked up again by the same process.  And even if it does there's no guarantee that future implementations of the JVM will behave the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity/blob/master/src/test/java/com/higherfrequencytrading/affinity/AffinityLockBindMain.java

Comment: @skytree Link repaired !

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this **will not** be possible unless you use native calls. JVM is supposed to be platform independent, any system calls done to achieve this will not result in a portable code.

Comment: I'm not concerned about portability.

Comment: @questzen: and what if the system call is made only if the Java program is found to be run on an OS supporting said call? The code would still be portable but simply not set any CPU affinity on other OSes.  This is the one thing that always crack me up: people screaming "non portable code" as soon as you do some JNI or some Runtime.exec().  I've got program that do both and that work on Linux, Windows and OS X.

Comment: It's not about whether to use or not use native calls but about whether the platform supports this "out of the box".  @questzen is right that the JVM will not abstract access to this because it's not very platform neutral.  You might be able to find third party libraries that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (at least with plain Java).

You can use [thread pools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to limit the amount of threads (and therefore cores) used for different types of work, but there is no way to specify a core to use.

There is even the (small) possibility that your Java runtime doesn't support native threading for your OS or hardware. In this case, [green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) are used and only one core will be used for the whole JVM.