# How to PIN a Java thread to a processor on Linux? (with JNI, native code, linux trick, etc.)

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java thread affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238272/java-thread-affinity)

I would like to test my 2-thread program running each thread on its own physical processor. I heard in linux you can PIN a thread to a certain processor so it stays there. Is there some kind of library in Java (using native code of course) that would allow me to do that? If not, can a Linux guru describe how do I pause my JVM, list my Java threads, get their native id and run some kind of linux command to PIN them? Then I can resume my JVM and the threads will bind to their assigned processor.

Comment: What is your goal? If you have 2 threads and 2 processors, most time each thread would run on a separate processor, and from time to time processors would swap their threads. Why does it matter for you?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov There are other threads in the OS and in my JVM, right? So my goal is to never allow (or to avoid the most I can) having my two threads running in the same physical processor.

Comment: @SergioOliveiraJr. I recommend looking at both the most upvoted answer and the accepted answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: @trutheality Yeah. I see now it is a duplicate. Thx!