# How java implements the streams in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, computer-science

I have a question been looking for an answer for a lot in the internet, I'm still new to concurrency, as far as I understand parallel is different from concurrency, parallel allow the program to execute faster and take advantage of multi core processors, after I have done some research I found that I can't do parallel programming nativly in java and I need to get some third-party library for that, my question is how java implemented parallel in streams, what packages it uses to implement that?

Comment: Not sure where you found that information.Just a simple search -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238272/java-thread-affinity. Answers your question.

Comment: It didn't answer my question :(

Comment: Ok. If you read it implies that the JVM assigns a thread per core. That you can not lock that pair from the JVM. Then if you start from the source -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html You can figure out that your question does not make much sense. I am not the person who down votes

Comment: Okay, I understand now

Comment: I am not trying to be mean. SO is great but there are a lot of bad answers. And a lot of SO cut-and-paste code in production that in those particular contexts makes no sense. Don't give up your thinking cap for SO.

Comment: Not a problem at all.